# Trying to share a file in OneDrive for several days already, and recipient email is not received

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, file-sharing

I'm trying to understand how OneDrive works.

Basically I'm sharing a file in my desktop, to my wife's laptop which is right in front of me, but I can't see the message sent to her email, after I share this file.

I know this email exists, for I've done this sharing a couple of weeks ago and it was working fine. Here are the steps I'm taking to share the alluded file.

1. I right click the file in my `OneDrive - Personal` and select `Share`, which then exhibits the OneDrive's Share dialog box (see picture below).

   [image]
2. I type my wife's email in the `To` field in the dialog and a message (below) to acknowlege her about this sharing.
3. Then I click on the `Send` button below.

At this point I was expecting to see an email message in my wife's laptop. But it doesn't get there and I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: Do you check your wife's spam folder?

Comment: I just did that, but couldn't find no emails sent to her by OneDrive.